# Create folder in dropbox from application

Tags: iphone, ios, dropbox

I'm making an iPhone application were I need to integrate Dropbox SDK. I'm getting error while creating a folder in Dropbox.Please anyone can tell me how to create folder.

Here is my code

```
(DBRestClient*)restClient { 
 if (restClient1 == nil) {
    restClient1 = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
    restClient1.delegate = self; }
    return restClient1; }

(IBAction)folderCreateMethod:(id)sender {
  [[self restClient] createFolder:@"/YourFolder"];

   }
```

I'm getting below error

```
-[__NSCFConstantString stringByAddingURIPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2fe5c
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What else have you tried?

Comment: Actually I searched a lot but could not find how to create folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringByAddingURIPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is not a method of NSString but likely defined in a category.

To use categories defined in another library -- where DBRestClient is -- you have to pass the `-ObjC` flag to the linker (in xcode)